# C++: Function automatically use 50 deduct/increase the input number before output

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to make a program that get user's integer input and then filter every single digit in that int into even number and odd number. There is no any mistake when I finished the code but the program did not run correctly as it should.

My code:

```
int main() {
    int input = NULL;
    int EvenNumbering = 0;
    int OddNumbering = 0;

    cout << "Please input a number: ";
    cin >> input;

    string str = to_string(input); //Convert it to string
    std::vector<int> EvenNo(str.length());
    std::vector<int> OddNo(str.length());

    //Now filter Even number and Odd number
    for (char x : str) {
    //for (int x = 0; x < str.length();x++ ) {
        //int z = (int)str.at(x);
        int z = (int)x;
        if (z % 2 == 0) {
            EvenNo[EvenNumbering] = z;
            EvenNumbering++;
        }
        else {
            OddNo[OddNumbering] = z;
            OddNumbering++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Even Numbers: ";

    for (int x : EvenNo) {
        cout << x << ", ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Odd Numbers: ";

    for (int x : OddNo) {
        cout << x << ", ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

If I input 1, the output is `Odd numbers: 49`
Whcih means it take 50 deduct the input I entered and display it out.

Comment: Look at the ASCII chart, and see if you can figure out why, all by yourself. If not, try compiling the following program: `int c='1'; std::cout << c << std::endl;` and see what you end up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch over to using `unsigned char` from `int` to give a more elegant solution.  Also `push_back` is the common way to add elements to a vector of unknown length.  Otherwise, you more or less had it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int input = 0;

    cout << "Please input a number: ";
    cin >> input;

    string str = to_string(input); //Convert it to string
    std::vector<unsigned char> EvenNo;
    std::vector<unsigned char> OddNo;

    //Now filter Even number and Odd number
    for (unsigned char x : str) {
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            EvenNo.push_back(x);
        }
        else {
            OddNo.push_back(x);
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Even Numbers: ";

    for (unsigned char x : EvenNo) {
        cout << (unsigned char)x << ", ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Odd Numbers: ";

    for (unsigned char x : OddNo) {
        cout << x << ", ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, thanks to the comment by Sam Varshavchik.

Solution:
Changed `int z = (int)x;` to `int z = (int)x-'0';`